# Is there a word for capitalizing in the middle of a word, as in "eBay"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, capitalization

Usually this sort of word is a trademarked name, such as *eBay* or *BlackBerry*.  Is there a word that describes capitalization mid-word?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This type of capitalization is best known as **camel case**, at least in programming jargon. But according to the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), the original name of the practice, used in media studies, grammars and the Oxford English Dictionary, was "**medial capitals**".

Comment: +1 Are you sure this really only for programmers?  It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I believe that *camel case* is more specific than *medial capitals*; it means using capital letters instead of spaces as word separators. So *BlackBerry* is camel case only if it's considered to be made up of "black" + "berry", rather than a weird spelling of "blackberry".

Comment: I am a programmer. I would like to make a small correction. eBay is `camelCase` whereas BlackBerry is `PascalCase` in programming jargons

Comment: Another way of differentiating between the two versions of camelCase in writing would be headlessCamels and ProudCamels.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2799326#2799326

Comment: One also occasionally sees the term "intercap" (short, I suppose, for intercapitalization).

Comment: @ManishSinha I've heard CamelCase used both ways.

Comment: @JoeZ. In programming world there isn't any one true method or organizations enforcing rules. BlackBerry is mostly called PascalCase and eBay called camelCase

Comment: *Camel case* is the overall phrase. The arguments over naming are subjective, and the various names used—more generically, *lower camel case* and *upper camel case*, can be seen in Wikipedia's entry for the phrase—as already linked in the answer.